# Mapview set as a list item is flickering

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a `Listview` with custom layout. One item in `Listview` is a `CustomView` which extends `RelativeLayout`. Which contains title, description, a `MapView` and two `Buttons`.

The problem which I am facing is the Map is flickering when I navigate from this screen or comeback to this. When we comeback to this screen it shows black colour instead of Map and changes to the map in 1 or  2 seconds. How can I get rid of this flickering on `Mapview`

Comment: try calling invalidate() on the MapView when you come back to the screen, to force it to redraw.

Answer (score 1):

Since MapView inside a ListView is a heavy operation to be performed, there is always flickering or wired behavior observed when these two functionalists are embedded together. Now here to get more consistency we have the following options:

- Build an URL like you would for a static Google Map, using several parameters that are necessary for my application. You can get more options here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

The code snippet to construct custome URL looks like this:

```
    String getMapURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=12&size=480x190&markers=size:mid|color:blue|"  
+ Jsonloc.getString("latitude") 
+ "," 
+ Jsonloc.getString("longitude") 
+ "&sensor=false";
```

This method return the map in form of a .png file. You can use the Fedor's Lazy Loading technique for bringing up that image whenever user would scroll up to that particular item in the list view. This would never flicker your map when it gets up on the screen.

- Use custom adapters (in case if you are not using). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) to guide you implement that, Since there is just one item having map.
- Final option is to use a button for eg "show map", that will send and intent to a different activity all together and show map and other detailed information about the list item of your list view.

Hope this would help!!